# How to generate response like below in Laravel 5.8

Tags: ajax, validation, laravel-5

This is the response which i'm getting if my ajax request ends up with validation errors...

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"email\":[\"The email field is required.\"]}","responseJSON":{"email":["The email field is required."]},"status":422,"statusText":"Unprocessable Entity"}
```

Want to generate response in similar format, if request processed successfully.
Would appreciate detailed description.

Went through various answers already posted here, but none of them help me out.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is just a JSON and laravel supports JSON resonses out of the box the only thing you have to do is to return an array with your data:

```
Route::get("/test", function() {
    $response = ["email" => ["The email field is required."]];
    return [
        "readyState" => 4,
        "responseText" => json_encode($response),
        "responseJSON" => $response,
        "status" => 422,
        "statusText" => "Unprocessable Entity"
    ];
});
```

Laravel returns every array as JSON and adds the `Content-Type: application/json` header to the HTTP request.

The example above gives you exactly your string: `{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"email\":[\"The email field is required.\"]}","responseJSON":{"email":["The email field is required."]},"status":422,"statusText":"Unprocessable Entity"}`

**EDIT:**
To set the status code you can use `response()->json()` like so:

```
Route::get("/test", function() {
    $response = ["email" => ["The email field is required."]];
    return response()->json($response, 422);
});
```

`response()` returns an instance of `Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory` so you can lookup the possible parameters: `function json($data = [], $status = 200, array $headers = [], $options = 0)`

Comment: This returns everything including status as part of the response, but Laravel's default validation error response returns status as part of header. Means when I view in network log, only `"email" => ["The email field is required."]` is visible. But in your case everything is visible in response.

Comment: You said you want your response `similar`, so I made it similar. But feel free to modify the array to return some other data. I edited my answer to show you how to change the status code.